# Invalid switch when trying to delete a file within a jenkins pipeline

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I have a  jenkins pipeline which build a C++ solution and then analyze some metrics and set the output to a temporary.csv file this file is treated and send to final.csv file. But o the step to delete the temporary.csv file I get an `Invalid switch` error. Probably an error due to my little knowledge of batch but I cannot find what is the error as executing the same command on the CMD works just fine

This is the step of my pipeline:

```
stage('Append to csv file') {
            steps {
                script{
                    bat """
                        echo( >> C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tool/temporary.csv
                        echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- >> C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tool/temporary.csv
                        echo %DATE% %TIME% >> C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tool/temporary.csv
                        C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tool/TopHeaders.exe D:/Project/outputTraceFile.etl >> C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tool/temporary.csv
                        find /v "Press" <C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tool/temporary.csv >> C:/Users/User/Desktop/CompilationTimes.csv
                        del C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tool/temporary.csv
                    """
                }    
            }
        }
```

and this is the output:

```
18:48:50  D:\Project>del C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tool/temporary.csv 
18:48:50  Invalid switch - "Users".
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DEL` only accepts *windows style* paths, with backslahes instead of forward slashes

You have to use

```
del C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tool\temporary.csv
```

Btw. The linux style is more reasoned, because the backslash is used as an espace character in many languages and the windows path style regulary breaks strings.   Therfore you often need to double the backslahes

```
del C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Tool\\temporary.csv
```

Sometimes it's even necessary to quadruple the backslashes

Comment: I have tried that but I get an unexpected char error in Jenkins if using forward slashes for any route, as the other commands works just fine with backslashes

Comment: @JesusFernandez Yes, it's ill thought through in windows. Double the backslash characters, the first one will escape the second one

Comment: @JesusFernandez, please read, [What should I do when someone answers my question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)